# Where can I find 20-pin IC Socket for the PIC16F690 in eagle ? which lib.?

Tags: microcontroller, eaglecad

[image: 20-pin IC socket]

Where can I find 20-pin IC Socket for the PIC16F690 in eagle ? which lib. ?

Comment: i do not think that there is a socket specifically for the PIC16F690 ... just choose a socket for the package that the IC is using

Comment: If you can't find a 20-pin socket, use header strips with the correct pitch (spacing) for the IC, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Uxcell-a14081900ux0270-Single-Straight-Header/dp/B012ACSO4Y/ref=sr_1_7 for 1/10"